# Issue when referring to instance of class:'Broadcaster (Socket) in Broadcaster cannot be applied to 0`

Tags: java, reference, instance

I have to create an instance of a class no call a nonstatic method. When I do this:

```
       @FXML
       public void initialize() {
       bConnect.setOnAction(d -> {
        try {
            new Broadcaster().serverConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

I receive this warning: `Broadcaster (Socket) in Broadcaster cannot be applied to 0`. 
I don't know what variable to refer to. How do I solve this?

This is the part of the Broadcaster class that has something to do with the socket:

```
public class Client {

private String serverAddress = "localhost";
private final int serverPort = 9001;

 @FXML
public void initialize() {
    bQuit.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());
    bConnect.setOnAction(d -> {
        try {
            new Broadcaster().serverConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

class Broadcaster extends Thread {
    Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader read;
    private PrintStream write;
    int counter = 0; //Countern finns för att testa funktionen.
    String questions;

    public Broadcaster(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void serverConnection() {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10000);

        Task<Void> connection = new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void call() {

                try {
                    clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the class Broadcaster, which was completely unnecessary. Now the method call works as intended!

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    bQuit.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());
    bConnect.setOnAction(d -> serverConnection());
    aliasField.setOnAction(a -> {

        alias = aliasField.getText();

        Input.setOnAction(b -> {
            userAnswer = Input.getText();
        });
    });
    aliasField.setPromptText("Alias");
    Input.setPromptText("And your answer is:");
}

public void main(String[] args) {
}

public void serverConnection() {
    try {
        ServerSocket quizSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10000);

    Task<Void> connection = new Task<Void>() {
```